# Probability of rolling two dice, one time ... (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, probability

Find the probability that you will roll either a seven at a craps table with a single roll of two dice or snake eyes (two). Assign the probability that you will roll a seven to a variable
called probSeven. Assign the probability that you will roll a two to a variable called
probSnakeEyes

---

> This is what Im thinking so far, however I'm having trouble programming a random roll of two dice?? Also to find the probability for a snake eyes could checking if `roll1 ==1 && roll2==1` work? Im just throwing some ideas out there, Im not sure yet what would be the most efficient. P.s Im a little sleepy so there may be some grammar errors. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
function P = diceroll(I,n)

%simulate n # of rolls

 if I = 7;

%first die

   for i = 1:6
%second die

      for j = 1:6
```

If I wanted to simulate rolling two dice (i and j), is the following code a possibility?  I'm only familiar with coding the roll one die in MATLAB. How would I implement two dice?

```
dice = randi([1,6],[1,n]);

%probability of rolling a I=7 from two dice

% n = simulated roll of die once, 

 probSeven = m/n
```

Comment: What kind of assignment is that? The only real solution I can see is to derive the probabilities properly, probably by pen and paper, and then say `probSeven = 6/36; probSnakeEyes = 1/36;`. I guess you could implement the counting in MATLAB, if you want … look up `meshgrid` and `nnz`. There's no room here really for actually rolling dice, unless you are explicitly told to “find” probabilities by approximating them experimentally.

Comment: Really, what's the problem? If you need to know probabilities only you can do it easily, as told @ChristopherCreutzig by simple calculation in mind, if you need to check it with some experiment (thousands of rolls etc), so yep it's another problem and we can help with it

Answer (score 2):

While this problem is quite easily to solve algebraically, or just by considering all possible combinations of 2 dice (only 36). If you want to do it by numerical simulation you can.

To roll two dice I would generate a 2*n matrix with randi. e.g. `randi(6, 2, n)`.

Then sum over the two dice to get the score for each dice and find the number of rolls that give the score you want.

Its important to note that this sort of numerical method will never give the exact answer and the accuracy of your answer will depend on the number of rolls. I would use n=1e4 as a minimum but it may be interesting to investigate how the result converges as n changes (although remember running the same number of dice again may give a different answer as it is a random process).